# Set child to content width, ignore parent width, and make parent scroll

Tags: css

With CSS alone, is it possible to obtain the following example, http://jsfiddle.net/LdJ7t/, without explicity knowing the child element's width before hand?

The final result desired:

- parent element scrollable to child element
- child element's width set to content

[image: Parent element scrollable to child content]

```
#Parent {
    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: .5em;
}

#Child {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}​

<div id="Parent">
    <div id="Child">
        This is a test. This is a test.
    </div>
</div>​
```

It looks like `display:inline-block;` almost works: http://jsfiddle.net/LdJ7t/1/

I think this is possible. I just can't find a solution.

Comment: So you want the child div to spawn a horizontal scroll bar? It's not very clear what your end goal is...

Comment: That's correct. Question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `inline-block` solution is correct - if you put longer words in or an image, the scrollbar will appear. Text is broken on white space by default.

If you don't want text breaking on white space, you can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the child div like here: http://jsfiddle.net/LdJ7t/2/